# Does Joomla v2.5 or v3 (in Beta) have support for custom user groups and permissions?

Tags: joomla

Having looked at Joomla during the v1.5 days I abandoned using it because it was limited to pre-defined user groups and non-granular permissions.

Now that v2.5 of Jooma is here and v3.0 is in Beta I am wondering if this has changed. Do the newer versions of Joomla allow more granular permissions and user defined groups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joomla 2.5 have ACL

One of the most powerful new features in Joomla 1.6 and later versions is Access Control Lists (ACL).

ACL stands for access control lists. It refers to who has permission to do what on the website, including read, create, edit, delete, or log in, among other permissions.

Here a helpful link

http://www.slideshare.net/jen4web/joomla-25-access-control-lists-acl